# hashes -- Seem like mutant potatoes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

What I have researched about hashes doesn't make them that much clearer to me... what I see is a new [THING] that I cannot see the value in right now.  I would RTFM if I could find one worth a beans instead of asking... here is what I was wondering...

I've been looking for answers for a few days now with now avail

- Where the heck is a syntax manual for Ruby and further more RoR.
- What are these things good for...
- I know twitter somehow relies on something of this nature but what is exactly

Comment: When learning a new language it really helps to have a good reference book. [The Pickaxe Book](https://pragprog.com/book/ruby4/programming-ruby-1-9-2-0) is usually a great place to start with Ruby, and that publisher has many other books related to Rails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a wealth of information out there, http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html for example is pretty clear on what hashes are.

You need to get your head around some of the basics, there are plenty of tutorials out there, https://www.railstutorial.org/ is one that comes up often, http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html is the most obvious place to start.

Comment: Oh My God! now I feel like a moron... how did I pass over that one... thanks

Comment: Should really bump that link to the 2.3.0 reference, that's the current version.